# getsockaddarg() error when using UDP sockets

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.x

I am trying to create a simple UDP connection, but fail miserably every time. I am using Python 3.5.2 with PyCharm.
        import socket
    from socket import AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM

```
ip = tuple(input('Enter an ip\n'))
#time = int(input('How long? In seconds \n'))
msg = 'Hello'
addr = (ip, 80)

def connection():
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    sock.bind(ip)
    sock.sendto(msg, addr)


connection()
```

The error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "A:/PycharmProjects/udp.py", line 15, in <module>
    connection()
  File "A:/PycharmProjects/udp.py", line 11, in connection
    sock.bind(ip)
TypeError: getsockaddrarg() takes exactly 2 arguments (14 given)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling `tuple` will construct a tuple containing each individual character in the iterable (the input string):

```
>>> tuple('127.0.0.1')
('1', '2', '7', '.', '0', '.', '0', '.', '1')
```

Don't use `tuple` just use the input you receive:

```
ip = input('Enter an ip\n')
msg = 'Hello'
addr = (ip, 80)
```

and bind on it:

```
sock.bind(addr)
```